# Adding controls to TabItems dynamically at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, tabitem

So, here is my issue, im working in a Wpf application, so i dont have all of the standard windows form controls.. so im attempting to use a windowsformshost, to hold a webbrowser inside of a tabitem. So here is what i have:

```
        Tab t = new Tab();
        Browser newbrowse = new Browser(t);
        WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
        Grid g = new Grid();

        host.Child = newbrowse;
        newbrowse.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        g.Children.Add(host);

        t.Header = "New Tab";
        t.Content = g;
        tabControl1.Items.Add(t);
```

now, Tab, and Browser, are just my custom implementations of the controls, and they both are tested and working. So that is not the issue. Now as far as i can see, that code should work. But I'm left staring at a blank tab page. Note that this will need to be in the codebehind and cant be included in the WPF itself.

Thanks for any input! :) Cheers

EDIT: Note that i have also tried the operation with the standard, controls.tabitem, and forms.webbrowser to the same effect

Comment: You know that there's a WPF WebBrowser control?  It was added in 3.5 SP1.  It backs onto the same ActiveX control as the WinForms one, but saves you having to muck around with WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: I must not have the SP, if i dont get an answer in a reasonable amount of time, i may consider upgrading. But if i can find a suitable method this way, I'd like to stick with my current setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this, and apparently what breaks your plan is the line:

```
newbrowse.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment it out, and watch how it suddenly works!